# Why does iPhone 4 lose its VPN connection on sleep or screen lock?

Tags: iphone, vpn

I've setup a VPN connection using AnchorFree.com on my iPhone 4 which works great, the issue I have is when my iPhone goes to sleep or screen locks the VPN connection appears to auto disconnect and doesn't reconnect unless I manually make it. I saw a thread [here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2333948) on apples forums confirming others are seeing this issue but no real solution.

Comment: Same here. iPod touch. Very annoying.

Comment: A question without question. Amazing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will really help you, but the only way I see to walk-around this problem is to set the System Preferences "Auto Lock" to "Never". This will keep you connection alive.

I would do this before every remote work session. Then, reset it to 1 minutes, you're done with it.

Comment: That seems to be a double security hole. First your iPhone won't lock, and then the thief will also have access to the VPN.

Comment: Yes others have mentioned this but I don't want turn off lock mode because it's inevitable that I will forgot to turn it back on leaving me at risk.

Comment: Have you ever used your iPhone as a hand calculator while working for instance ? If you don't turn this autolock during that time, you'll become mad. If there are right : there should be an app for that ! An app that switch the auto-lock on at startup, no ?

Comment: or rather, a way to declare certain apps as "not security-relevant". They could then be accessed without unlocking the phone. The whole thing opt-in, of course.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a **battery-saving option**. If only it would do that with Wi-Fi connections.... :(
Being connected to a wireless signal besides 2G data eats the battery like mad.

Answer (score 0):

I have just signed up for VPN service this week and I have been having the same problem. I use it to watch Netflix and listen to Pandora from out of the country. I have been playing around to see if I can get the VPN to stay connected; so far I found a solution that has been working for about an hour or so now.

I have a jailbroken iPhone 4 and I have installed backgrounder from Cydia which keeps programs running even when closed or when the screen is off.

After installing this, I installed Pandora from the App Store and, after launching it, I held down the home button to background it.

So far, it seems to be working because Pandora uses my connection and if I keep it backgrounded, it will prevent the VPN from disconnecting.

I have only been using it for a couple of hours so I'm not sure how good of a permanent solution it will be.